# Testing Concept Activation Vector (TCAV) for Pytorch

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, activation-function, efficientnet

I am trying to compute the Testing Concept Activation Vectors ([TCAV, as described here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11279)) vectors for different concepts for my classification model. So far, I haven't successfully found code online for Pytorch models so I have decided to rewrite it myself. The code I am trying to copy is:

```py
def compute_tcav(input_tensor, model, AA, layer_name, filter_indices, optimizer, seed_input=None, wrt_tensor=None, backprop_modifier=None, grad_modifier='absolute'):
   
    layer_AA = AA[layer_name]
    
    losses = [
        (ActivationMaximization(layer_AA, filter_indices), -1)
    ]
    
    opt = optimizer(input_tensor, losses, wrt_tensor=wrt_tensor, norm_grads=False)
    #grads = opt.minimize(seed_input=seed_input, max_iter=1, grad_modifier=grad_modifier, verbose=False)[1]
    
    return losses #utils.normalize(grads)[0]
```

source: https://github.com/maragraziani/iMIMIC-RCVs/blob/master/rcv_utils.py

This is what I have so far:

```py
def ActivationMaximizationLoss(input_AA):
    loss = torch.mean(input_AA)
    return loss
def compute_tcav_pytorch(model, layer_predictions):
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 1e-4)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    input_AA = torch.from_numpy(layer_predictions['_blocks.6._project_conv']) # middle    
    input_AA.requires_grad=True
    
    loss = ActivationMaximizationLoss2(input_AA)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    img = input_AA.grad
    
    return img[0][0]
```

I am trying to maximise a layer activation from the model and from that get the TCAV vector.

Comment: Where is this approach going wrong so far? It's hard to tell what your specific question is. To start though I will point out that calling `optimizer.step()` clears the accumulated gradient for the parameter groups in the optimizer, so you should attempt to examine the gradient before then.

Comment: My question is if the code for Pytorch compute_tcav() is correct, when compared to the Keras version. I don't have any experience with Keras, and there is no ActivationMaximization function for Pytorch.

Comment: Pytorch implementation of `ActivationMaximization`: https://github.com/Nguyen-Hoa/Activation-Maximization

Comment: The ActivationMaximiation code outputs an image though, and from the implementation in my question I need the losses. How do I do this?